# How to do conditional formatting of colour scale in VBA in a more efficient way?

Tags: excel, vba, colors, pivot-table

As i wanted to conditional formatting of colour scale in the range as shown below, i recorded the macro while doing it. The code will work but i encountered the "procedure is large error"(compile error) when i do the same thing for 36 pivottables. So is there a way to decrease the size of the procedure so that i can do it for 60 pivotables?

The type of conditional formatting that i used for my colour scale

[image]

[image]

```
Sub test()

    Range("B5:J12").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
        xlConditionValueLowestValue
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
        .Color = 7039480
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = _
        xlConditionValuePercentile
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
        .Color = 8711167
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = _
        xlConditionValueHighestValue
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
        .Color = 8109667
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ScopeType = xlSelectionScope
End Sub
```

Error message

[image]

Comment: Please explain the "procedure is large" error. There are compile errors and runtime errors. Runtime errors usually have a number and a proper description. They are notified in a message box in which you can click a `Debug` button which leads to the line of code that caused it. All of that is vital information in the context of your question.

Comment: @Variatus the prodcedure is large refers to the compile error. By clicking debug, it doesn't bring me to the error line.

Comment: @Variatus so very likely is due to the long line of codes here which has potential to reduce to make it more efficient?

Comment: Can you post a picture of the error message, please? I'm rather confident that the code has nothing to do with the error, certainly not the length of its lines, and suspect that you might hit the limits of formats that can be applied. My tendency would be to use the code to apply formats based on its own evaluation. I think CF is intricate and, ultimately, troublesome, as your question would appear to confirm.

Comment: You need to extract the formatting code into a separate sub, and call it from the main code - no need to repeat virtually the same lines over and over.

Comment: @Variatus i just posted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract the formatting code into a separate sub, and call it from the main code - no need to repeat virtually the same lines over and over.

For example:

```
Sub Main()
    ApplyFC Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5:J12")
    ApplyFC Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B5:J12")
    'etc etc
End Sub

Sub ApplyFC(rng As Range)

    With rng.FormatConditions.AddColorScale(ColorScaleType:=3)
        .SetFirstPriority
        .ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
        With .ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
            .Color = 7039480
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        .ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValuePercentile
        .ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
        With .ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
            .Color = 8711167
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        .ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
        With .ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
            .Color = 8109667
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        .ScopeType = xlSelectionScope
    End With

End Sub
```